# Как посчитать расстояние между двумя точками?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как посчитать расстояние между двумя точками?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в консоль вывел две точки, как мне посчитать расстояние между ними? Как называется эта формула, которая это делает и как она записывается?

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame       ||
           mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
           webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
           msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})(); 

function createPath(from, to) {

 function elemPosition(elem) {
  let pos = {
      top: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      left: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      right: window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      bottom: window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  };
  return pos;
 }

 function centerElem(elem) {
  let width = elem.offsetWidth;
  let height = elem.offsetHeight;
  let centerX = width/2 + elemPosition(elem).left;
  let centerY = height/2 + elemPosition(elem).top;
  let pos = {
   y: centerY,
   x: centerX
  };
  return pos;
 }

 function render(childF, childT) {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('harmony');
  document.body.append(div);

  let start = {
   x: centerElem(childF).x,
   y: elemPosition(childF).bottom
  };

  let final = {
   x: centerElem(childT).x,
   y: elemPosition(childT).top
  };

  let myReq, count;
  console.log(start.x, start.y);
  console.log(final.x, final.y);
  function stepReq(div) {
   
   myReq = reqAnimFrame(stepReq);
  }
  stepReq(div);



 }

 let childFrom = from.children[0];
 let childTo = to.children[0];

 centerElem(childFrom);
 render(childFrom, childTo);

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 createPath(items[0], items[4]);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 max-width: 1400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.line:not(:first-child) {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper > div {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.item {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 40px;
}

.item__img:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.line {
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="line line__one">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__one -->

 <div class="line line__two">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__two -->

 <div class="line line__three">

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
   <div class="item__img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
   </div>
  </div>

 </div> <!-- .line__three -->


</div> <!-- .wrapper -->
```

Comment: *Как называется эта формула, которая это делает* :facepalm: Формула Пифагора она называется... [Теорема Пифагора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: можно [тут](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points) подглядеть

Comment: Извините, что в гугл не написал, затупил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расстояние между двумя точками A1(x1;y1) и A2(x2;y2) в прямоугольной системе координат выражается формулой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]